# How to prevent sqlite3 to Auto-Increment the Primary Key if Null value is specified?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

So, I am creating a simple GUI in `Python` using `Tkinter`.
[image]
Now, when the user leaves the `Roll Number` (*i.e. primary key*) label widget empty and tries to insert the data, I will be inserting `None` instead of an empty string and I want to throw an `Error` but instead the data gets inserted with an *auto-incremented* Roll Number value. **I don't want the Primary Key to get inserted if the Roll Number label widget is left empty.**

> This the code I am using for Creating the Table

```
c.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE students(
    enroll_no integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name text NOT NULL,
    middle_name text,
    last_name text,
    course text NOT NULL,
    semester integer NOT NULL
    )
""")
```

> And this the code for Inserting into the Table

```
    try:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO students VALUES (:inp_rn, :inp_fn, :inp_mn, :inp_ln, :inp_course, :inp_semester)",
            {
                'inp_rn':inp_rn.get() if inp_rn.get() != "" else None,
                'inp_fn':inp_fn.get() if inp_fn.get() != "" else None,
                'inp_mn':inp_mn.get() if inp_mn.get() != "" else None,
                'inp_ln':inp_ln.get() if inp_ln.get() != "" else None,
                'inp_course':inp_course.get() if inp_course.get() != "" else None,
                'inp_semester':inp_semester.get() if inp_semester.get() != "" else None
            }
        )
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
        messagebox.showerror("Insertion Failed","Insertion Failed")
```

Comment: ther might b a better way, but what i did was, i took the entry box related to roll number and said if `e1.get() == '':` messagebox or anything will be okay here, `else:` put all the code of databse below this block. Note that this has to go inside of the functio that the button is calling

Comment: You can't. An `integer primary key` column is an alias for the `rowid` number, which must be present. It's how sqlite works.

Comment: @CoolCloud Ya that should work, Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if it did work, so i can add that as an answer:)

Comment: @CoolCloud Ya that worked! Please upvote if possible.

Comment: can u provide your entry box name related to roll number

Comment: @CoolCloud Its inp_rn, also can you please tell how to prevent user to insert a string into semester column, it has to be integer. But if the user inserts a string it gets inserted right now!

Comment: ***prevent user to insert a string***: Read [how-to-tell-user-to-only-use-integers-if-they-input-string-in-python-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848360)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple `if`, `else` statement to tackle this error. Let entrybox related to roll no. be e1. Paste all the blocks of database after and paste it below `else` block, Please consider upvoting too

```
if e1.get() == '':
   messagebox.showerror('Please Fill','Please specify roll number to proceed')
else:
................
................
```

To simply check if an a variable is `int()` or not, you can use `.isdigit()` which returns a boolean. First assign a variable to your `e1.get()` then follow as here. Remeber that only pure digit can be used, any use of hyphen(-) or special characters will result in execution of `else` block :)

```
checking = e1.get()
if checking.isdigit() == True:
    .........
else:
    messagebox.showerror('Integrity Error','It must be a integer')
```

Comment: Can you please also tell how to prevent user to insert a string into semester column, it has to be integer. But if the user inserts a string it gets inserted right now!

Comment: Updated answer with one of the possible methods but remember that it can make your code more nested inside of `if` statements, that shouldnt be an issue but ya keep in mind.But  as a small piece of advice use MySQL so u have more control over the data being entered  :)